# Servlet Working fine on local Server, but Unable to Invoke Same Servlet on Real cpanel Live Server

Tags: java, servlets

I am working with the Java Web Application Where user Should Invoke a servlet with the Url like
 (This works fine when i run my project on my local server, Login is a Java Class extends HttpServlet).

But When i upload my project to Live Server through FileZilla FTP client

i am unable to invoke the Servlet with the Url like
www.mydomain.com/myproj/Login(Server returning Error 404)

Please see my Images and please kindly help me..

Thank you in advance..

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2CnH.jpg)
[web.xml for Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS39n.png)

Comment: Hello , please consider editing the question and add proper image links, from your edit history I found link for [web.xml](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lTHA9.png) , But Project Structure is not available in the edit history.

Comment: Update: I have Attached my project structure image link and Server side xml link. Please kindly help me..

Comment: Login servlet is not mapped in your web.xml file

Comment: Sorry, that was the changes by me as a trails.. by oversight i have uploaded with other mapping code but infact i tried by keeping Login in servlet mapping but not working

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake..

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

if i map my servlet as above it is working.. but the another problem i am facing is, i am unable to invoke a servlet if i dont use "servlet" in my url mapping.. which obviously tells to the user what technology i am using.. how can i use my servlet without mentioning servlet in url pattern